# Sampling texture with MTLPixelFormat.r32Float

Tags: metal

I have a texture with MTLPixelFormat.r32Float, and I would like to sample it with linear interpolation using texture.sample(mySampler, float2(u, v)). I am configuring the sampler as:

```
constexpr sampler mySampler (mag_filter::linear,
                             address::clamp_to_edge,
                             min_filter::linear);
```

However, within a metal Shader, texture.sample() always returns a 4-component vector (float4). So my questions are:

1. Can the sampler interpolate the texture with MTLPixelFormat.r32Float correctly?
2. If so, which component of the sampler output (float4) represents the sampled value?

So far, I have been unsuccessful at finding this out experimentally. None of the components of the sample output seem to work. Is it possible I have to configure sampling differently? Or is it impossible?

Comment: Are your UVs set correctly? What is your device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A texture with **MTLPixelFormatR32Float** pixel format can not be [filtered during sampling](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf) on most GPUs.

According [Metal Shader Language Specification:](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

> For unspecified color components in a pixel format, the default values
> are:
>
> - zero, for components other than alpha.
> - one, for the alpha component.

---

> If so, which component of the sampler output (float4) represents the
> sampled value?

You can use an **array index** to access vector components:

```
float c = texture.sample(mySampler, float2(u, v))[0];
```

or swizzling:

```
float c = texture.sample(mySampler, float2(u, v)).r;



float c = texture.sample(mySampler, float2(u, v)).x;
```

Comment: What does it mean cannot be filtered? Does it mean linear interpolation won’t work during sampling, just nearest?

Comment: Yes, linear interpolation won’t work during sampling.

Comment: okay thank you! Btw I see I can sample from it and the result is in the first component of float4, so all good. No interpolation is not obvious, it doesn’t seem to complain/fail when I use sampler with interpolation, maybe it’s just ignoring it instead of failing